# fullCalendar v1.5.1 - ie7 & ie8 - SCRIPT5007

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, fullcalendar

I am getting the following error in ie7 and ie8

`SCRIPT5007: Unable to set value of the property 'source': object is null or undefined 
fullcalendar.min.js?ver=3.1, line 28 character 264`

Full Calendar is being used as part of the ["eventify" plugin for wordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/eventify/)

Currently using `FullCalendar v1.5.1`.

I updated this from `FullCalendar v1.4.7` due to a similar error in `v1.4.7`

Any Thoughts??

--Just a quick note: I never ended up resolving this. I gave up on it and moved on --

Comment: Can you post your code to initialize fullcalendar?

Comment: Good question... I didn't write the plugin. I'll see if I can figure it out

Comment: property source is NULL . Somewhere you are trying to add a NULL source. Where.. difficult to say.

Comment: or the calendar is not properly loaded and object SOURCE is null and cannot be set

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using FullCalendar v1.5.2.

The exact error was (fullcalendar wasn't minified) :

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to set value of the property 'source': object is null or undefined 
fullcalendar.js, line 918 character 7
```

The piece of code in fullcalendar was :

```
for (var i=0; i<events.length; i++) {
   events[i].source = source;
   ...
```

`events.length` returned 75 but only had 74 elements in it.
I found the answer [here](http://jszen.blogspot.com/2004/07/array-length-headaches.html) : the event list had a comma after its last element. Removing it should fix it for IE < 9.